# Check status of a non-Twilio number when forwarding a Twilio number to multiple phones

Tags: twilio, voicemail

not sure how much sense my title makes.

Is there a way to check the status of a non-Twilio number before Twilio forwards a call to this number?

Use case: we forward calls to a Twilio number to three different cell phones. We also send a notification with which number ended up taking the call to all the three phones, after the call is over.

Problem: very often, the voicemail of one of our three phones answers the forwarded call, which we want to prevent.

Question: is there a way to check whether a cell phone is currently available (no voicemail would answer!) before forwarding a call to that number?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe exactly what you are asking for is possible. However, let me suggest an alternative that may get the job done.

- When a call comes in, place the caller in a queue.
- Initiate a call to your three phone numbers.
- Ask for the person(s) you called to press one and gather the response.
- The first person to press one has the queued call forwarded to them.